# Remove rows that do not contain certain words/phrases

Tags: list, csv, batch-file

I need to remove some rows from a list.

I need to remove all of the rows that do not contain certain words or phrases.

I am using code that removes certain rows.  I need to change this code to save only the rows that contain certain words

I am using this code

```
:: 'Remove Lines With Specific Words From Proxy List Csv'
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

findstr /v "GOOD WORKING" "C:\my_list.csv" > "C:\my_list.new"
del "C:\my_list.csv"
ren "C:\my_list.new"  *.csv
```

I need to adapt the code to delete all rows except the rows that contain "GOOD WORKING" can you help me please ?

Comment: remove the `/V` switch?

Comment: This code remove only the rows that contain "GOOD WORKING" i need to remove ALL rows eccept the rows that contain "GOOD WORKING"

Comment: In that case, remove the `/V` switch.

Comment: npocmaka - rojo Thanks to all the solution working like a charm. you are best coder, thanks agains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehm - I object!

```
findstr /v "GOOD WORKING" "C:\my_list.csv" > "C:\my_list.new"
```

shows all lines that do not contain either `GOOD` or `WORKING`.

```
findstr "GOOD WORKING" "C:\my_list.csv" > "C:\my_list.new"
```

shows all lines that contain either `GOOD` or `WORKING`.

```
findstr /v /C:"GOOD WORKING" "C:\my_list.csv" > "C:\my_list.new"
```

shows all lines that do not contain `GOOD WORKING`.

```
findstr /C:"GOOD WORKING" "C:\my_list.csv" > "C:\my_list.new"
```

shows all lines that contain `GOOD WORKING`.

Unless preceded by the `/c:` switch, the target string is a space-separated list of words.